# Problema con iTextSharp

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, itextsharp

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static void FillForm(srting texto1)
    {
        string pdfTemplate = @"C:\Template.pdf";
        string newFile = @"C:\New Template.pdf";
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        // set form pdfFormFields  
        // The first worksheet and W-4 form  
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", texto1);
        // report by reading values from completed PDF  
        string sTmp = "W-4 Completed for " + pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_09(0)") + " " + pdfFormFields.GetField("f1_10(0)");
        MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Finished");
        // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false  
        // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits  
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;
        // close the pdf  
        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
```

El cual es para llenar un formulario PDF, el problema que tengo es que me está dando el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Justo en esta línea: PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));

Ya estuve investigando en todos lados, probé cambiando el código, probando las formas diferentes que hay en internet pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error. La verdad no entiendo, sé que puede referirse a que el archivo no existe pero sí está. Lo que noté es que al crear el nuevo archivo PDF me da un error (Quiero suponer que es porque se queda como abierto y se daña) adjunto imagen:

[image: PDF dañado después de la excepción]

Espero me puedan apoyar a guiarme para solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.